# Gnome-keyring iteration count location

Tags: passwords, linux

I know that Gnome-keyring hashes the master password between 1000 and 2000 times. It picks a random number. I would like to ask where it saves this number, what is the location of that file? As far as I know it needs this count number when decrypting the files with saved passwords.

Answer (score 1):

According to my reading of the source code (`docs/file-format.txt`), the iteration count is stored in the keyring file, specifically in the 25th through 28th bytes after the end of the keyring name.